# how to represent big numbers in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sum

I have big numbers and when I try summing them the result I get is just 3 digits.

```
emp1   |tar
11850 | 150,000 
11850 | 100,000 
11945 | 200,000
11945 | 200,000
```

when i use the below query i am expecting to see 11850 = 250,000 and 11945 = 400,000
however i get 11850 = 250.0 and 11945 = 400.0

```
query = """
SELECT 
emp1,
sum(tar)
from Sum
group by emp1
"""
```

Cna i get help in expanding these numbers to show in thousands and Millions

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are misunderstanding your data. Apparently, the comma is the decimal separator, not the thousand separator.

Comment: thanks for that, i did not realize commas were used as decimal separators.

Comment: @user14140366 no the commas are not considered as decimal separators. A value like `150,000` even if the data type of the column is REAL or NUMERIC is considered as TEXT, because of the presence of the comma. So when SQLite implicitly converts the value to a number to perform the SUM, it converts it to the starting part of the value that can be converted to a number. This part is the digits up to the comma.